# Many deleted users

Tags: support, user-accounts

Apparently, quite a number of users have been deleted in the last month or so. I've noticed it because, as I haven't been very active lately, my rep score has been declining due to their removed votes.

I saw that 155 users [have been deleted](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12628/75633) in the whole year, so unless they'd been very active in voting, the 5 I noticed seem quite a lot.

Is there some sort of end-of-the-year clean up taking place, an exodus, or is it just a fluke?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It's probably a coincidence. 155 users were deleted and 46 destroyed by moderators, but that doesn't include self-deletions. I don't know of any way to get specific numbers of how many users delete their own accounts, but as far as I can tell it accounts for the bulk of overall account deletion. In your specific case, as far as I can tell only 1 of the 5 was deleted by a moderator.

I won't go into specific numbers, but if anything December was a slow month as far as moderation is concerned. Certainly there wasn't an end of the year clean up on our part.

Comment: I thought so. I was annoying nonetheless, so I had to ask. :-D

Comment: But I'd really be curious to know how many users deleted their own accounts.

Comment: @stafusa I'm curious too, but I can't think of any way to get that number with the information available to me.

Comment: I also noticed a number of "user deleted" in the last month.

Comment: A lot of user deletions by moderators are related to sock-puppet activity. We occasionally get people who create a bunch of accounts or repeatedly re-create a single account at a time in an effort to evade bans or suspensions. Both cases can result in clusters of deletions in relatively short times. If those uses *also* repeatedly vote for your content then you get to see the activity.

Comment: That said, a significant number of deleted sockpuppets never get around to voting. So if you notice your reputation falling, odds are good it was a self-deletion. As seems to be the case for 4 of the 5 drops that @stafusa noticed.

Comment: Thanks for the information, @Chris . I guess it's then down to my focusing on complex-systems questions - I can imagine many people get curious about chaos, come to Physics SE for a question, but don't have a general interest in physics, so they leave shortly after. I'll have to live with it. :-/ BTW, your comment really is an answer, will you post it as such?